# RasterStack/Brick for multiple variables from multiple files in multiple folders R

Tags: r, date, maps, time-series, raster

```
library(raster)
```

I am working on a relatively complex task and need tips on how to accomplish it.

- My data are raster time series from 1910-2000 at daily time scale.
- Each raster (`.asc`) file represents a time step.
- The data is stored in folders with each folder containing data for 1 year (91 folders in total). There are 1095 files in each folder. Of these 1095 files, Tmin=365, Tmax=365, and precip=365 corresponding to 365 days in a year.All years are formatted as leap years with 29 days for February and Julian day 60 are missing in the no-leap years.
- In each folder, the three variables (Tmin,Tmax,precip) are labelled as `max1910_1.asc,min1910_1.asc, precip1910_1.asc` etc up till 365.

TASKS:

1) I would like to import all files into R. I can get the file paths using:

```
files <- dir("C:/data//, recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE, pattern="\\.asc$")#
```

2) Make a rasterstack/brick for each variable i.e. TminStack, TmaxStack and PrecipStack.

In each of the three separate rasterstacks, layer1 should be Jan-01-1910 and the last layer is data for Dec-31-2000.

3) Finally, I will have 3 time series rasterstacks corresponding to Tmax, Tmin, and precip. I can set the time axis in the three rasterstacks using:

```
dates=seq(as.POSIXct("1910-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2000-12-31"), by="day")
TminStack <- setZ(TminStack,dates)
TmaxStack <- setZ(TmaxStack,dates)
precipStack <- setZ(precipStack,dates)
```

I could not supply a reproducible example because the files are large and stored in separate folders for each year.

Many thanks,

Sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the files based on their name, something like this:

```
TminStack <- list.files(path=".", pattern=paste("min",".*.asc",sep=""), all.files=FALSE, full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE)
```

Comment: In each folder, the file names for the three variables are labelled as `max1910_1.asc,min1910_1.asc, precip1910_1.asc` so if I run;`TminStack <- list.files(path=".", pattern=paste(min,".*.asc",sep=""), all.files=FALSE, full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE)`; I get the error `Error in paste(min, ".*.asc", sep = "") : 
  cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'character'`. In task 1 in the question I can read all file paths. The problem is how to extract paths with min, max and precip and form separate rasterstacks?

Comment: the code worked great except that the file names are not well sorted which means `raster::stack` won't stack the time series correctly except if `stack` sorts the file names internally. These is what I got: > `head(TminStack)
[1] "./canada_daily1950/1950/min1950_1.asc"   "./canada_daily1950/1950/min1950_10.asc" 
[3] "./canada_daily1950/1950/min1950_100.asc" "./canada_daily1950/1950/min1950_101.asc"
[5] "./canada_daily1950/1950/min1950_102.asc" "./canada_daily1950/1950/min1950_103.asc"` but using `require(gtools) 
TmnStack=mixedsort(TminStack)` gives the correct file order.